# calculate mean value across multiple objects using same index/variable name [javascript/jquery]

Tags: javascript

NOTE: I worked out an answer after writing this question, but am still posting as I haven't found this question elsewhere on SO.

I have an object with a structure like the following where I'd like to calculate the mean across the objects in "original_array" for their variable "this_value".

```js
original_array = [
  {
    this_value:5
  },
  {
    this_value:10
  },
  {
    this_value:2
  }
]
  
//calculate mean of across all objects in original_array for "this_value" in each of them.
```

I imagine there are elegant ways to do due to the consistency of the structure of the objects across the array.

I have tried

```js
original_array = [
  {
    this_value:5
  },
  {
    this_value:10
  },
  {
    this_value:2
  }
]

// SOLUTION:
var total = 0;
original_array.forEach(function(element){
  total += element.this_value;
});
var this_mean = total/original_array.length;
console.dir(this_mean);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my solution. Hope this helps.

```js
function calcMeanByField(arr, field) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item[field], 0) / arr.length;
}

const original_array = [
  { this_value: 5 },
  { this_value: 10 },
  { this_value: 2 },
];

console.log( calcMeanByField(original_array, 'this_value') );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var original_array = [
    {
        this_value: 5.0
    },
    {
        this_value: 10.0
    },
    {
        this_value: 2.0
    }
];

var this_mean = original_array.reduce((total, next, index, array) => (index === array.length - 1) && (total + next.this_value) / array.length || total + next.this_value, 0);

console.log(this_mean);
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper array method to use when turning an array into one value (such as a sum) is `.reduce`:

```js
const original_array = [
  {
    this_value:5
  },
  {
    this_value:10
  },
  {
    this_value:2
  }
];
const sum = original_array.reduce((sumSoFar, { this_value }) => sumSoFar + this_value, 0);
const mean = sum / original_array.length;
console.log(mean);
```

`.forEach` is for when you're doing something that isn't appropriate to any of the other array methods, such as something that has side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - just to clarify on your point - is this because of efficiency specifically, or is there a risk of forEach giving unexpected output?

Comment: It's not efficiency, it's for code readability. When you see a `.reduce`, you immediately know "This is going to iterate over each element in the array exactly once and spit out a single value at the end." On the other hand, a `forEach` could do any number of things - you don't quite know what it's accomplishing without reading the whole way through it.

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing it (though would be happy if there are shorter/more elegant alternatives).

```js
original_array = [
  {
    this_value:5
  },
  {
    this_value:10
  },
  {
    this_value:2
  }
]

// SOLUTION:
var total = 0;
original_array.forEach(function(element){
  total += element.this_value;
});
var this_mean = total/original_array.length;
console.dir(this_mean);
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19218210)

Comment: @marco.m someone else added my answer to the main question - I think the answer I've posted is complete (though I think the other answers posted are better).

Comment: If this or any other answer solves your problem, mark it as accepted and upvote other answers that you find useful.